# NextJS getServerSideProps pass data to Page Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i know this has probably been already asked, but i'm at a point where i don't know what to do.
I'm not a (very) experienced developer in javascript or NextJS.

**My Problem(1)**:
I got the method: `export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {}` implemented to fetch some data from a integrated API (`pages/api` from NextJS). The code itself is probably not well(or worse) written, but it works. (for now at least)

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
    try {
        // get userID
        await fetch("http://localhost:32147/api/v1/user/get?requestedField=userID&fieldName=username&fieldValue=<value removed>").then(
            (userIDResponse: Response): any => {
                // get userID as json
                userIDResponse.json().then((userIDResult: Response): any => {
                    // get messages
                    fetch(
                        "http://localhost:32147/api/v1/message/get?requestedField=*&fieldName=userID&fieldValue=" +
                            JSON.stringify(userIDResult[0].userID)
                    ).then((messageResponse: Response): any => {
                        // get messages as json
                        messageResponse.json().then((messageResult) => {
                            return {
                                props: { messages: messageResult },
                                {/* marker1 */}
                            }
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

just to be clear, this method works, data fetching works but just if i access it at **marker1**
that one part where i return the props:

```js
return {
props: { messages: messageResult },
}
```

i can't do that 'cause nextjs is gonna break because of getServerSideProps() didn't return anything.
I tried to store the final data into a variable, that i declared on the first line of this method, but it ended up being empty the whole time.

How can i solve this?

**My Problem(2)**: if i set a manual value at the end of this method for testing, it doesn't get passed to the main Page Class (index.tsx)
i can just access it using `this.props.<prop name>`, in this case: `this.props.messages`, right?

The whole `index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next"
import Router from "next/router"
import Head from "next/head"

import Navbar from "../lib/Navbar"
import MessagesModal from "../lib/MessagesModal"

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
    try {
        // get userID
        await fetch("http://localhost:32147/api/v1/user/get?requestedField=userID&fieldName=username&fieldValue=<value removed>").then(
            (userIDResponse: Response): any => {
                // get userID as json
                userIDResponse.json().then((userIDResult: Response): any => {
                    // get messages
                    fetch(
                        "http://localhost:32147/api/v1/message/get?requestedField=*&fieldName=userID&fieldValue=" +
                            JSON.stringify(userIDResult[0].userID)
                    ).then((messageResponse: Response): any => {
                        // get messages as json
                        messageResponse.json().then((messageResult) => {
                            return {
                                props: { messages: messageResult },
                            }
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

interface HomeProps {
    messages?: []
}

export default class Home extends Component<HomeProps> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    state = {
        messagesModal: false,
        messages: [],
    }

    // triggers logout
    triggerLogOut(): void {}

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <>
                <Head>
                    <title>OneDrive Event Connector</title>
                </Head>
                <Navbar
                    ItemClickCallback={(callbackItem: string): void => {
                        if (callbackItem === "messages") {
                            this.setState({ messageModal: !this.state.messageModal })
                        } else if (callbackItem === "log_out") {
                            this.triggerLogOut()
                        } else {
                            Router.push("/" + callbackItem)
                        }
                    }}
                />
                <div className="app-content"></div>
                <MessagesModal
                    messages={this.props.messages}
                    isOpen={this.state.messagesModal}
                    toggleModal={() => {
                        this.setState({ messageModal: !this.state.messagesModal })
                    }}
                />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

This is just a "fun" project for me to practise and learn. 
Would be greate if anyone could give me even a hint on what is my problem/mistake here...

Thanks.

Kind regards 
Oliver

Comment: You're mixing `await`s with `then`s. The nice thing about `await` is that you can write your code as if it were synchronous, which among other things helps you avoid the pyramid of doom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i can't do that 'cause nextjs is gonna break because of getServerSideProps() didn't return anything.

exactly - in your code, you are returning values inside of a chain of promises - you need to make sure, that values are returned from each step

here's a working example - similar flow with swapped API - to help you understand how to return something, going back from the inside of your chained promises

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
    try {
        // initial fetch
        const result = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
            .then((todosResponse: Response): any => {
                return todosResponse.json().then((todo) => {
                    // fetch something more
                    return fetch(
                        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + todo.userId
                    ).then((userResponse: Response): any => userResponse.json());
            })
        })
        return {
            props: { messages: result },
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

My advise is also to read more on promises / async await in JS world

> My Problem(2)
> i can just access it using this.props., in this case: this.props.messages, right?

yes, that's right

```
interface HomeProps {
    messages?: []
}
export default class Home extends Component<HomeProps> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {JSON.stringify(this.props.messages)}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```